# Como obtener los datos de un usuario nuevo

Tags: sql-server

mi problema es el siguiente quiero obtener todo lo que hizo ese usuario de 6 dias de antiguedad. Lo pense asi pero no me arroja ningun resultado y hay transaciones dentro del rango puesto

la consigna es OBTENER LAS TRANSACCIONES QUE HIZO EL USUARIO NUEVO por eso pongo el DATEDIFF en el where  para que me de la antiguedad (la condicion que pense yo es que me traiga todos los datos del usuario menor a 6 dias de antiguedad)

Alguna IDEA? gracias de ante mano!

```
select TransaccionId, AccountCode, NetAmount, nombreApellido_usuario from TablaPrincipal
left join Usuarios on TablaPrincipal.UserId = Usuarios.Id_usuario
where DATEDIFF(day,Usuarios.fecha_alta,GETDATE()) <= 6
```

tabla usuarios

```
TABLE [dbo].[Usuarios](
    [Id_usuario] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [username] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [contraseña] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [nombreApellido_usuario] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [email] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [esAdmin] [bit] NULL,
    [fecha_alta] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [TransactionID] [int] NULL,
```

tabla Principal

```
TABLE [dbo].[TablaPrincipal](
    [TransaccionId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AccountCode] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NetAmount] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [DocumentType] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NULL,
    [JournalDescription] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [LineDescription] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Id_movimiento] [int] NULL,
```

Comment: Y cual seria el problema con ese query? podrias ser mucho mas claro? mostrar un ejemplo de datos, que estas recibiendo y que esperas recibir?

Comment: No me trae ningun dato la query dada!

Comment: Estara mal el query? no habra datos que cumplan con eso? no tenemos forma de saber porque no trae datos.. cuales son los datos que deberia traer? que datos tiene la tabla?